# Android Java implement 2 buttons in 1 page

Tags: java, android, xml, button

I finally learned about adding a button to a page and actually making it navigate to another activity "XML Page". Anyway, I have been trying to add 2 buttons in the same page which navigate each to a different XML's Pages. All I did was copy the first button which worked and then change the button name and all other things the first button works but the second isn't. It shows a click but nothing happens after.
Back1 Button works. TMode Button does the trouble.
Eclipse is not showing errors.

Here is my code -

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class GameMode extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created.*/
    Button btn;
    Button btn1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_mode);

        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Back1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(btn2Listener);
    }

    private OnClickListener btn2Listener=new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent2=new Intent(GameMode.this,MainActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent2);
        }
    };

    public void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_mode);

        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.TMode);
        btn.setOnClickListener(btn3Listener);
    }

    private OnClickListener btn3Listener=new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent3=new Intent(GameMode.this,CharacterSelect.class);

            startActivity(intent3);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener; 
import android.widget.Button;

public class GameMode extends Activity {

Button btn1;
Button btn2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_mode);

    btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Back1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(btn1Listener);

    btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.TMode);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(btn2Listener);
}


private OnClickListener btn1Listener=new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent1=new Intent(GameMode.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
        }
    };
private OnClickListener btn2Listener=new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent1=new Intent(GameMode.this,CharacterSelect.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
        }
    };     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should in your XML file define two buttons

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/button1"
   ... />

<Button
   android:id="@+id/button2"
   ... />
```

And then in your Activity in `onCreate()` method you do

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    ...
})

Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: @ByteHamster i tried your method.. it now transfare to the other XML but for some reason the app crash once it transfare

Comment: Never Mind i solved it.. i had to delete some extra imports i had in the destination XML

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener; 
import android.widget.Button;

public class GameMode extends Activity {

Button btn1;

Button btn2;

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_mode);

    btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Back1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(btn1Listener);

    btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.TMode);

    btn2.setOnClickListener(btn2Listener);
}


private OnClickListener btn1Listener=new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent1=new Intent(GameMode.this,MainActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent1);
        }
    };
private OnClickListener btn2Listener=new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent2=new Intent(GameMode.this,CharacterSelect.class);

            startActivity(intent2);
        }
    };     
}
```

Comment: Isn't this exactly what @ByteHamster suggested? You should have accepted his answer instead.

Comment: Yeah but i am new here i didnt know i have a way to accept the answer.. but done :) did that !